# Set Rows Visible Depending on Row Value in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview

My goal is to be able to set visible to false the rows that do not have the id that I am looking for.

```
 string id = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                            where dr["Occupation"] == DBNull.Value
                            select (string)dr["testID"]).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {                        

                    /*INSERT CODE*/
                }
```

Pretty much set rows the rows that do not have the same id.
The table that I am using is this:[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnqKY.png) 
For example, id will return 568, so I would want to set visible the other rows that do not have id=568

I have been trying but i cant seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{ 
   if(row.Cells["testID"].Value == id){
      row.Visible = false;
   }
}
```